# 'str' object is not callable; ptyhon

Tags: python, twitter-oauth

```
class MyListener(tweepy.Stream):
    def on_data(self,data):
        try:
            data = json.loads(data)
            tweet = data['text']
            print(tweet)
            with open('tweet.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                saveFile = open('gabung.csv','a')
                f.write(tweet)
                f.write('\n')
                f.close()
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print('Failed'(e))
   
    def on_error(self,status):
        print(status)
        
twitter_stream = MyListener("consumer_key","consumer_secret",
  "access_token", "access_token_secret"
)
twitter_stream.filter(track=['jokowi'])
```

and the result is error

> SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a
> comma?   print('Failed'(e))

Comment: What is your intent in writing `print('Failed'(e))`? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: If you wanted `print('Failed'(e))` to print the error, the error message pretty much says it, `perhaps you missed a comma`

Comment: Please include the full traceback message so we can see the failing line.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given in the error. Python tells you that you're missing a comma, just add that and you should be good to go.

```
print('Failed',(e))
```

Comment: The parens around the `e` are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling a string :

for what I think you want to do you should :

```
print('failed' , e)
```

instead of:

```
print('Failed'(e))
```